# Winform control getting cropped in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

I'm having problem trying to include a winform user control in WPF. My control gets cropped whatever I try to do.

The control keeps autosizing itself even when I have not set the option.

Here's what it looks like

[image]

Here's the XAML

```
<Window x:Name="mainForm" x:Class="RFID.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RFID"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:gei1076_tools;assembly=gei1076_tools"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="755.682">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <sp:SerialPortConfigurator x:Name="spcConfigurator" ></sp:SerialPortConfigurator>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Does putting the WindowFormsHost in a ViewBox help?

Comment: I smell a dpi awareness problem.  Considering modifying the user control so it does not autosize itself for the simplest fix.

Comment: I'll try both suggestions tomorrow. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @NickB So what did you find? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I have touch this for a while. I don’t remember. Sorry.